# RecursionError in json encode and FastAPI

Tags: python, openai-api

When using and endpoint of an API I am getting a recursion error. The weird thing is that if I don't make it an endpoint and just use it in the code I do not have any error. I saw something similar here https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2030 that it might be a circular reference, but I am not finding anything. The error is the following:
   `File "/Users/x/.virtualenvs/y/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 331, in jsonable_encoder     return jsonable_encoder(            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/x/.virtualenvs/y/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 287, in jsonable_encoder     encoded_value = jsonable_encoder(                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/x/.virtualenvs/y/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 331, in jsonable_encoder     return jsonable_encoder(            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/x/.virtualenvs/y/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 331, in jsonable_encoder     return jsonable_encoder(            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/x/.virtualenvs/y/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 287, in jsonable_encoder     encoded_value = jsonable_encoder(                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/x/.virtualenvs/y/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 331, in jsonable_encoder     return jsonable_encoder(            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/x/.virtualenvs/y/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 279, in jsonable_encoder     encoded_key = jsonable_encoder(                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/x/.virtualenvs/y/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 216, in jsonable_encoder     if isinstance(obj, BaseModel):        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Here is the code of the API (I included what I think it matters and the all the imports in case):

api.py:

```
from utils.pdfToText import pdfToText
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from repository.document_repository import Document, add_document
from repository.base_model_repository import BaseModel
from repository.embedding_repository import generate_embeddings, get_top_matches, Embedding, get_embeddings
import uvicorn
app = FastAPI()

database = BaseModel.get_database()
@app.get('/search')
def search_chunks(query: str, n: int = 5):
    return get_top_matches(query, n)
```

repository/embedding_repository.py

```
from repository.base_model_repository import BaseModel
from repository.document_repository import Document
from pgvector.peewee import VectorField
from peewee import ForeignKeyField, TextField
from utils.createChunks import create_chunks
from utils.client import create_embeddings

class Embedding(BaseModel):
    url = ForeignKeyField(Document, backref='embeddings')
    text = TextField()
    embedding = VectorField(dimensions=1536)

def get_top_matches(query, n):
    query_emb = create_embeddings(query)
    res =  Embedding.select().order_by(Embedding.embedding.cosine_distance(query_emb)).limit(n).dicts()
    return res
```

client.py:

```
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI()

def create_embeddings(text, model="text-embedding-3-small"):
    text = text.replace("\n", " ")
    return client.embeddings.create(input = [text], model=model).data[0].embedding
```

Any idea will be much appreciated, I've been with this for a while now

Tried to refactor the code, look for circular references, but haven't found anything really

Comment: Try to increase recursion depth (not a better solution) -> import sys; sys.setrecursionlimit(9000000)
Have you juggled with Asynchronous call while instantiating Embedding ?

Comment: Not working if I increase the recursion depth, it just keeps thinking for a really long time. And no, I didn't

Answer (score 0):

Your `res` contain at least one element which refer to the parent. Try to iterate through values and return only this values which you really need.